# Can I Guarantee that MoveFile() will not Lose a File if it Fails?

Tags: c++, winapi

Given a CRITICAL file named:

```
C:\Lvl1\test.file
```

that I want to move to:

```
C:\Lvl1\Lvl2\test.file
```

Using the ::MoveFile() function, can I rely on MoveFile() to not lose the file data if the function call fails?

The code to execute this would probably be something like:

```
int main()
{
   bool bMoveFileFailed = false;

   // Please just accept that a "CalcCRC32()" exists and returns the file CRC32!
   uint crcOriginal = CalcCRC32("C:\\Lvl1\\test.file");
   if( FALSE == ::MoveFile("C:\\Lvl1\\test.file", "C:\\Lvl1\\Lvl2\\test.file") )
   {
      bMoveFileFailed = false;
   }
   std::cout << "MoveFile() " << (bMoveFileFailed ? "FAILED" : "SUCCEEDED") << std::endl;

   uint crcNew = CalcCRC32(bMoveFileFailed ? "C:\\Lvl1\\test.file" : "C:\\Lvl1\\Lvl2\\test.file");

   if ( crcNew == crcOriginal )
   {
      std::cout << "The File Integrity was maintained!" << std::endl;
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "The file was corrupted or lost!" << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should check its documentation.

Comment: @NathanOliver the docs do not say anything about that https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: On the same drive (volume) it does a rename, on different drives it does a copy then delete see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx  You need to be aware that the file security may not be what you expected see the difference between same and different volumes

Comment: Your question is not so logical _rely on MoveFile()_, You can track the error fail with `GetLastError()` every time. Usually `MoveFiles` fails on writing to the new place that points to security write permissions. Question is not right at all.

Comment: Ali, I'm not sure I follow why you think the question is wrong. I'm worried about using a MoveFile() to move critical data from one directory to another on a single volume. Is it possible for the file to be lost if say the computer loses power in the middle of the MoveFile()? (This is a very real scenario)

Comment: With ReplaceFile, the original file remains untouched (well, except maybe for file attributes) on error. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @AliSepehri-Amin: Your interpretation of the question is not what the question is about. The OP is asking about exception guarantees, namely the strong guarantee. In other words: If the function call fails, is it guaranteed that all side-effects have been rolled back. I'm sure the OP knows how to evaluate, whether the function call succeeded or not, and how to proceed in either case.

Comment: _Is it possible for the file to be lost if say the computer loses power in the middle of the MoveFile()?_ - This is less a question about `MoveFile()` (or any other high level API) but about the robustness of the underlying filesystem (propably NTFS) and the actual storage hardware. See this question for instance: [Is NTFS fail-safe in case of a power outage?](https://superuser.com/q/194412/730625)

Comment: @zett42, I guess the power failure wasn't a very good example. I'm really more concerned about a software failure, so perhaps the executable that makes the call to MoveFile() has another thread crash during the move, or an Anti-virus decides to lock the file during the move.

Comment: @Catachan, assuming that "Lvl2" isn't an NTFS mountpoint of another volume, then this is a within-volume rename via the `NtSetInformationFile` system call with the information class [`FileRenameInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540344). The rules listed there are generally right, but they're too strict for an open file. If all of the previous opens shared delete access, then you're allowed to open it with delete access and renaming will succeed.